# AFNetworking and auth token Error Code -1011

Tags: ios, token, afnetworking-2, http-status-code-401

I'm sending data between and iOS app and a web server with an auth token system. The token was generated through a login API with JWT and then stored locally on the device. When I use it later in a loading data request I'm getting a -1011 error with status code 401.
Here's my code:

```
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kBaseURLString];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"token": authtoken};

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager POST:@"load_data.php" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        [self doSomeStuff:responseObject];
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Unable to load data"
                                                            message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }];
```

If I test my php API with curl and the same auth token it works well. But with the iOS simulator I get this error:

```
ERROR: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)" UserInfo=0x79f848f0 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7ad59d90> { URL: http://localhost:8888/load_data.php } { status code: 401, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 12;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html;charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Mon, 17 Aug 2015 16:03:44 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.8 PHP/5.6.2 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8za DAV/2 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.20.0";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.6.2";
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:8888/load_data.php, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unauthorized (401), com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<556e6175 74686f72 697a6564>}
```

I'm getting the same error using a GET method. But when I copy/paste the url from the error message of the console to my browser it works like a charm. I don't understand why the AFNetworking request fails on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting Authorization header using [setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFHTTPRequestSerializer.html#//api/name/setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:) of request serializer?

```
/**
 Sets the value for the HTTP headers set in request objects made by the HTTP client. If `nil`, removes the existing value for that header.

 @param field The HTTP header to set a default value for
 @param value The value set as default for the specified header, or `nil`
 */
- (void)setValue:(NSString *)value
forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString *)field;
```

An example of this is written below, but each server can specify how tokens are formatted in authorization headers. If you need something different, you can always set that header value yourself.

```
[requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"token %@", yourToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Comment: Yes thanks it works with authorization header.

However the main problem came from a claim of the token data structure in my php code. The token began to be valid 10 seconds
after being issued. I tried to use it before this time so I set the notbefore claim to 0.